# Get Thymeleaf @{} expression to append locale

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

My context path is `/` and I'm adding locales directly as part of the path: `/de/index.html`.

Now I'm facing the problem that `th:href="@{/login.html}"` will resolve to `/login.html` instead of `/de/login.html`.

I already tried making a Filter and an Interceptor like they did it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23847484/1163457

But it still won't append `de/` after the context path.

Writing my own dialect and attribute processors would be a solution, but isn't there any better one?

Comment: yup in our project we had similar requirement we implemented dialect and processors

Comment: But in my opinion that's not a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a clean and good solution myself after hours of step debugging:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60103777/1163457

Answer (score 1):

Why not expose a model attribute for the locale (e.g. curLocale) and redefine all your urls like

```
th:href="@{/${curLocale}/login.html}"
```

Thymeleaf allows other expressions inside url expressions themselves.
Locale information is easily accessible either as a method parameter or by calling RequestContext.getLocale()

Comment: That seems to be the only way without writing my own dialect. But I don't want to put the locale in every link. So this is not an option for me.